# Insert into table from select query + variables values

Tags: asp.net, insert, webmatrix

I want to insert into the  table tb2 (QuestionID, QuestionStem, UserID, ExamID) a set of rows selected randomly from table tb1 (QuestionID, QuestionStem) along with values for the two columns UserID, ExamID which are fixed for one insert query. I have tried this query in webmatrix, but I got an error that @ should not be in this location in the insert query statment:

```
db.Query("INSERT INTO tb2 (QuestionID, QuestionStem, UserID, ExamID) SELECT QuestionID, QuestionStem, @UserID, @ExamID FROM tb2");
```

Any help is appreciated. I am using webmatrix 3.0 to build my app. 
Note, UPDATE statement after insert will not work as there will be simultaneuos users and I want to present the selected row based on UserID and ExamID per user.

Answer (score 1):

You can't accomplish your task with a single parameterized query in Webmatrix and, in my opinion, it's not a good solution create a query concatenating parameters.

A better alternative could be extract from table t1 the records you need and insert them one by one with a foreach loop:

```
@{
    var userId = 25;
    var examId = 32;
    var sql1 = "SELECT TOP 10 QuestionID, QuestionStem FROM t1 ORDER BY NEWID()";
    var sql2 = @"INSERT INTO tb2 (QuestionID, QuestionStem, UserID, ExamID) 
        VALUES (@0, @1, @2, @3)";
    var db = Database.Open("yourDb");
    var data = db.Query(sql1);
    foreach (var row in data){
        db.Execute(sql2, row.QuestionID, row.QuestionStem, userId, examId);
    }
}
```

**Edited**

If performances are a real concern, maybe the best solution is to migrate data from Sql Server Compact to Sql Server Express.

In this environment you could create a Stored Procedure like

```
CREATE PROCEDURE AddQuestions @UserID int, @ExamID int
    AS
    INSERT INTO dbo.tb2 (QuestionID, QuestionStem, UserID, ExamID) 
    SELECT TOP 10 QuestionID, QuestionStem, @UserID AS UserID, @ExamID AS ExamID
    FROM dbo.t2 ORDER BY NEWID()
GO
```

and recall it in WebMatrix:

```
@{
    var userId = 14;
    var examId = 16;
    var db = Database.Open("yourDb");
    var data = db.Execute("EXEC AddQuestions @UserID = @0, @ExamID = @1", 
       userId, examId);
}
```

Comment: Not to disagree with your answer, because I understand the desire to avoid concatenation, but this method is an order of magnitude less efficient than my answer. I don't see a problem with concatenating type safe integers into a command as long as you understand the risks and are aware of what you're doing in a more general sense. For just ten rows on a website that sees little traffic this method is better in that it avoids 'dangerous' ground, but if `sql1` was selecting thousands of rows it could take seconds to complete instead of a couple of milliseconds.

Comment: @Polynomial, I agree with you that my solution is less efficient than yours but, if performances are a concern, maybe Sql Server Compact is not the right choice. I have edited my answer.

Comment: A fair point, and your edit is worthy of an up-vote. To be fair though, the question doesn't specify what SQL version they are using (I know you can infer it from the comment on my answer, but the question itself is general enough) and I'd say it's always worth going through the relative pros and cons of each approach. Always better for the programmer to be able to make an informed decision.

Comment: Thank you for your very constructive comments.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you could use numbered ordinals for the two parameters. Something like this, but setting the variables to use your data as appropriate of course:

```
var userId = 0;
var examId = 0;
db.Query("INSERT INTO tb2 (QuestionID, QuestionStem, UserID, ExamID) SELECT QuestionID, QuestionStem, @0, @1 FROM tb1", userId, examId);
```

You also mentioned you want the rows from `tb1` to be selected randomly. You can achieve this by adding `ORDER BY NEWID()` to the end of the `SELECT` statement in your query:

```
db.Query("INSERT INTO tb2 (QuestionID, QuestionStem, UserID, ExamID) SELECT QuestionID, QuestionStem, @0, @1 FROM tb1 ORDER BY NEWID", userId, examId);
```

If you want to limit it to a number of rows only you can do (for example, with ten rows):

```
db.Query("INSERT INTO tb2 (QuestionID, QuestionStem, UserID, ExamID) SELECT TOP 10 QuestionID, QuestionStem, @0, @1 FROM tb1 ORDER BY NEWID", userId, examId);
```

Comment: It did not work.  Error msg:A parameter is not allowed in this location. Ensure that the '@' sign is in a valid location or that parameters are valid at all in this SQL statement.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException: A parameter is not allowed in this location. Ensure that the '@' sign is in a valid location or that parameters are valid at all in this SQL statement.

Comment: I guess you could just directly concatenate the parameters into the string, taking care to avoid injection hack vectors (which should be easy as they are both integer values).